# Ember Data. How to sent to the server attributes which are not defined in model?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

If I receive extra attributes (which not defined in a model) from the server I will not store them in ember model. Thus on `PUT` or `POST` I will not send them to the server.

Is there a way to keep these extra attributes as "cashed data" and send them back to the server?

Comment: create one field called 'cachedData' or whatever on your model.  in your serializer, munge the incoming data so that you set 'cachedData' to be the data you want to keep. you might have to use a raw transform for that field. also in your serializer, for outgoing data just reverse the process. i don't know what you're actually trying to do, but this should basically do what you want

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by costumizing your serializer for sending and receiving data, 
for example if you are using JSONAPIAdapter you use a serializer as follow :

```
export default class YouRouteSerializer extends JSONAPISerializer {

  //for sending data
  serialize(snapshot, options) {
    let json = super.serialize(...arguments);

    //add a vlue that doesnt exist in the model
    json.data.attributes.theNewAttributeName =  'example';

    // delete a value 
    delete json.data.attributes.theAttributeNameToBeDeleted;

    return json;
  }


 //and for receiving (this is what you are looking for)

normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {

    let extratData = payload.data.attributes.yourExtratData;
    // here store you extrat data somewhere else , localstorage for example
    // thenn
    // delete your extra data
    delete payload.data.attributes.yourExtratData;

    return super.normalizeResponse(...arguments);
  }
}
```

here is a reference for customizing a serializer [Customizing Serializers](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-serializers/)